# Spacy - preprocessing & lemmatization taking long time

Tags: nlp, text-processing, spacy, lemmatization

I am working on text classification problem and I have tried WordNetLemmmatizer then followed by TF-IDF, CountVectorizer. Now, I am trying to clean up the text using Spacy before feeding to TF-IDF. Input file has around 20,000 records with each record having few sentences. Overall size of the file is 45MB.

Lemmatization using WordNet was taking only few seconds. But below code using Spacy is taking too long. After 20 mins my laptop get hanged. Kindly advice how to optimize Spacy for text pre-processing and lemmatization.

I am using Spacy 2.0.12.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'tagger', 'ner'])

def spacy_lemma_text(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    tokens = [tok.lemma_.lower().strip() for tok in doc if tok.lemma_ != '-PRON-']
    tokens = [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in nltk_stopwords and tok not in punctuations]
    tokens = ' '.join(tokens)
    return tokens

df['spacy_lemma_text'] = df['text'].apply(spacy_lemma_text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Several possible explanations come to mind:

- `nltk_stopwords` is a list, not a set, so checks like `tok not in nltk_stopwords` take linear time instead of constant. Try adding `nltk_stopwords = set(nltk_stopwords)` before your function definition
- you might be running other spacy models, not just lemmatiser and tokeniser. Better to be explicit (example from https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer):

```
    from spacy.lang.en import English
    tokenizer = English().Defaults.create_tokenizer(nlp)
    tokens = tokenizer(u'This is a sentence')
    assert len(tokens) == 4
```

- are you loading the spacy model more than once?
- as unlikely as this is, you might be running out of memory. Paging to disk will slow you down a lot. Check in your system monitor/task manager

Comment: As suggested I have tried using `nltk_stopwords = set(nltk_stopwords)` but still its taking long time and not getting the results. 

As part of pre-processing I am trying to lemmatize the words and join them and add to new pandas dataframe column.  And I am only loading spacy model only once in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using spacy's nlp.pipe function if you are iterating over multiple documents. This will allow you to incorporate a batch size as well as multithreading. Spacy is not set up to work the way that you have suggested.

Additionally, using nltk's stopwords is going to be a bottleneck, I think. If you are using spacy, go ahead and use spacy's stopwords instead. They should be optimized for use in spacy, as opposed to nltk.

```
import spacy
from spacy.attrs import *
import numpy as np

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
texts = ["this is some sentence","This is the last sentence"]
max_length =10

data = np.zeros((len(texts), max_length), dtype=np.uint64)

for row, doc in enumerate(nlp.pipe(texts, n_threads=8, batch_size=10000)):
    dat = doc.to_array([LEMMA, IS_STOP])
    # Check to see if text length is not 0
    if len(dat) > 0:
        delete = np.where(dat[:, 1] == 1)
        dat = np.delete(dat, delete, 0)
        length = min(len(dat), max_length)
        data[row, :length] = dat[:length, 0].ravel()
```

This will leave you with spacy hash data stored in a numpy array. This hash data can then be converted by accessing spacy's vocabulary. I don't have time to test this right now, but my guess is it will be much faster. Hope this helps.